# Rust-resistant 4x4 base for concrete?

Tags: concrete, steel, rust-proofing

I've read several reviews about this [Simpson 12-Gauge E-Z Base](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026T7AZG) that say that they began rusting after a few months.

I wanted to use them, but they'll be used at a house next to the ocean, so I'm worried that they'll just rust super fast.

Are there any alternatives to these bases that are rust-resistant or should I just rust-proof them?

Or is this something that I just shouldn't be worried about?

Comment: You can also get post bases in stainless steel. If the area is near enough to the ocean to get misted or sprayed with sea water, I think they are recommended.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-4-in-x-4-in-16-Gauge-Stainless-Steel-Adjustable-Post-Base-ABU44SS/205227042.   Simpson makes stainless post base.  A little pricey though.